# React Axios fetch response with error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Not sure why my api response is not rendering in UI. It does successfully displayed the response in console though.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {result}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap'

const TextGenerator = () => {
  const [usertext, setUsertext] = useState('hello')
  let [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // const text = { usertext }

    axios
      .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/computer programming`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.data)
        result = res.data
        setResult({ result })
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
  }

  return (
    <div className='text-center .w-75'>
      <br />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          required
          size='80'
          placeholder='Enter text...'
          value={usertext}
          onChange={(e) => setUsertext(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Generate Text</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {loading ? <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation='grow' /> : { result }}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TextGenerator
```

Comment: if the response be a json, React throw the error.
becuase React can't show json as a child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React` sees below `object` when it tries to render the `result` in `state`.

```
{
    result: {
        result: <your_data - res.data>
    }
}
```

Try

```
{loading ? <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation='grow' /> : result}
```

instead of

```
{loading ? <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation='grow' /> : { result }}
```

React cannot render `object` like `{ result }`

And It will still fail since you wrap and save the `result` as an `object`.

Change

```
setResult({ result })
```

To

```
setResult(result)
```

This will still fail if `res.data` is not a type of `string` or `array` of `JSX`/`string`  Elements.

Comment: @syedshabbir, check this out !!